# Pass Parameter with Menu Click - Asp.Net BoilerPlate

Tags: c#, angularjs, aspnetboilerplate

currently we are using angularJS with Asp.Net Boilerplate

We have a navigation menu item called listings, when it's clicked, it redirects to listings.

Code to trigger that is as followed.

AppNavigationProvider.cs

```
AddItem(new MenuItemDefinition(
        PageNames.App.Common.Listings,
        L("Listings"),
        url: "listings",
        icon: "icon-home",
        requiredPermissionName: AppPermissions.Pages_Listings)
```

App.js

```
$stateProvider.state('listings', {
    url: '/listings?id',
    templateUrl: '~/App/common/views/listings/index.cshtml',
    menu: 'listings'
});
```

My goal is to extend this page by adding a new parameter to app.js.

```
$stateProvider.state('listings', {
    url: '/listings?id&addNew',
    templateUrl: '~/App/common/views/listings/index.cshtml',
    menu: 'listings'
});
```

My question is, how do I enhance AppNavigationProvider so that it can pass a parameter with the url?

I tried

```
AddItem(new MenuItemDefinition(
    PageNames.App.Common.Listings,
    L("Listings"),
    url: "listings?addNew=1",
    icon: "icon-home",
    requiredPermissionName: AppPermissions.Pages_Listings)
```

But I am presented with the error `Could not resolve 'listings?addNew=1' from state 'dashboard'`

Any tips on adding a navigation menu item with parameter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a repro project on GitHub?